# Catching outgoing calls in a service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to catch an outgoing call in a service and by now I would expect something in the debugger console.

I create a `DailerReceiver` (who is added in the manifest and extends the `BroadcastReceiver`). Then I add an `IntentFilter` with `android.intent.action.NEW_OUT_GOING_CALL` and register the receiver. Also I enable the service in the manifest. I expect those are the required steps.

There is also some more information in the manifest. I'm unsure whether that is really necessary but added it in the example to get the whole picture.

Piece of the service:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        DialerReceiver mReceiver = new DialerReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Class `DialerReceiver`:

```
public class DialerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        debugOut("arg0: " + arg0.toString());
        debugOut("arg1: " + arg1.toString());
        debugOut("isOrderedBroadcast = " + isOrderedBroadcast());
    }

    private static void debugOut(String str) {
        Log.d("DialerReceiver", str);
    }
}
```

Part of the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<receiver 
    android:name=".DialerReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".BackgroundService"
    android:enabled="true">            
    <intent-filer>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>                
    </intent-filer>
</service>
```

Full error log from the minute a test call took place:

```
03-14 09:28:32.095: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState0
03-14 09:28:32.095: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState0
03-14 09:28:32.140: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState0
03-14 09:28:32.140: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState0
03-14 09:28:32.370: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState36
03-14 09:28:32.370: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState36
03-14 09:28:32.420: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState32
03-14 09:28:32.420: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState32
03-14 09:28:32.880: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState779
03-14 09:28:32.880: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState779
03-14 09:28:33.065: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState779
03-14 09:28:33.065: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState779
03-14 09:28:33.730: E/SpannableStringBuilder(31997): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-14 09:28:33.730: E/SpannableStringBuilder(31997): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-14 09:28:35.195: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState5
03-14 09:28:35.195: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState5
03-14 09:28:35.300: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState154
03-14 09:28:35.300: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState154
03-14 09:28:35.405: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState154
03-14 09:28:35.405: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState154
03-14 09:28:35.530: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState154
03-14 09:28:35.530: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState154
03-14 09:28:35.620: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState37
03-14 09:28:35.620: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState37
03-14 09:28:35.765: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState37
03-14 09:28:35.765: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState37
03-14 09:28:35.850: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState7
03-14 09:28:35.855: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState7
03-14 09:28:35.995: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState7
03-14 09:28:35.995: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState7
03-14 09:28:36.050: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState7
03-14 09:28:36.050: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState7
03-14 09:28:37.735: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount before onRestoreInstanceState5
03-14 09:28:37.735: E/TwAdapterView(31997): TwAdapterView AdapterDataSetObserver onChanged ItemCount after onRestoreInstanceState5
03-14 09:28:37.775: E/SpannableStringBuilder(31997): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-14 09:28:37.775: E/SpannableStringBuilder(31997): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-14 09:28:39.155: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=DIALING, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=0, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:39.155: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn()
03-14 09:28:39.155: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn(): headset is not connected!
03-14 09:28:39.170: E/TinyUCM(1921): There aren't inputs in map or set stereo(0)
03-14 09:28:39.170: E/TinyUCM(1921): Stereo is already enabled
03-14 09:28:39.170: E/TinyUCM(1921): modifier doesn't exists any more
03-14 09:28:39.205: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=DIALING, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=2, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:39.205: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn()
03-14 09:28:39.205: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn(): headset is not connected!
03-14 09:28:39.390: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=DIALING, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=2, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:39.390: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn()
03-14 09:28:39.390: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn(): headset is not connected!
03-14 09:28:39.435: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=DIALING, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=2, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:39.435: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn()
03-14 09:28:39.435: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn(): headset is not connected!
03-14 09:28:41.820: E/TinyUCM(1921): modifier doesn't exists any more
03-14 09:28:42.920: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=ALERTING, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=2, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:44.300: E/TinyUCM(1921): There aren't inputs in map or set stereo(2100000)
03-14 09:28:44.300: E/TinyUCM(1921): Stereo is already enabled
03-14 09:28:44.300: E/TinyUCM(1921): modifier doesn't exists any more
03-14 09:28:45.205: E/Watchdog(2277): !@Sync 1113
03-14 09:28:46.555: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=ACTIVE, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=3, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:46.555: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn()
03-14 09:28:46.555: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOn(): headset is not connected!
03-14 09:28:50.105: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=OFFHOOK, mFCall=DISCONNECTING, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=0, mCall=1, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:50.555: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOff(): mPendingScoForA2dp: false, mPendingScoForWbs: false, mConnectedSco: null, mA2dpState: 11, mA2dpSuspended: false, mVoiceRecognitionStarted: false
03-14 09:28:50.605: E/TinyUCM(1921): modifier doesn't exists any more
03-14 09:28:50.605: E/TinyUCM(1921): modifier doesn't exists any more
03-14 09:28:50.605: E/TinyUCM(1921): Builtin Mic: active count 1
03-14 09:28:50.605: E/TinyUCM(1921): Back Mic: active count 1
03-14 09:28:50.605: E/TinyUCM(1921): modifier doesn't exists any more
03-14 09:28:50.840: E/ActivityThread(2853): Failed to find provider info for com.cequint.ecid
03-14 09:28:55.470: E/BargeInRecognizer(2853): stopBargeIn
03-14 09:28:55.515: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): handlePreciseCallStateChange() mPhone=IDLE, mFCall=IDLE, mBCall=IDLE, mRCall=IDLE, mCallsetup=0, mCall=0, mCallheld=0
03-14 09:28:55.515: E/Bluetooth HS/HF(2853): audioOff(): mPendingScoForA2dp: false, mPendingScoForWbs: false, mConnectedSco: null, mA2dpState: 11, mA2dpSuspended: false, mVoiceRecognitionStarted: false
03-14 09:28:55.900: E/WifiP2pStateTracker(2277): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: WIFI_P2P[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
03-14 09:28:58.175: E/WifiHW(2277): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
03-14 09:28:58.385: E/WifiHW(2277): ##################### set firmware type 0 #####################
```

Comment: you want it to catch the outgoing call even always? or only while the application is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you are trying to register the broadcast reciever in the service. And also - are you calling startService() from your activity? If so - you do not need

```
<intent-filer>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>                
</intent-filer>
```

in manifest for service. I just created a sample app with your code, excluding the intent-filter for the service, and my onRecieve worked fine.

Comment: Seems that when I remove that intent-filer aswell it works perfectly.

Comment: TYPO ALERT ! Thats <intent-filter>  !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add this

```
    <intent-filer>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>                
    </intent-filer>
```

in manifest. Because you are registering receiver in service's onCreate().

And you don't need to register receiver in manifest too because of the same reason.

Check you have added **android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS** permission in manifest.

To try alternate method: check [this](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/07/listening-to-phone-calls-using.html) out.

Comment: Removing the the intent from the filter didn't help (didn't do bad things either). `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` was already in the manifest just removed a little too much for this example.

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I added the error log for one minute in which a test call took place. I don't see an error that is (in my view) associated with this issue.

Comment: BTW, the service is running. At least, the same service catches the PhoneStates aswell. That part works great.